# How to export data in CSV in kibana custom plugin using Reporting plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

how can I `export data` which I rendered in a `dataGrid` inside of a custom `plugin` using `data plugin`

- How did I render the `data` inside a `plugin`?
  follow -> [Git app.tsx](https://github.com/AzharUddinSheikh/testing/blob/PaginatedData/public/components/app.tsx)

[image: myPlugin rendering data in kibana]

I want to `export` this `data` using the `kibana plugin` 
`Dashboard plugin` has an example for exporting `data`

[image: exporting data in dashboard plugin of kibana]

Answer (score 0):

To export these datas, you can use the kibana's API.

To find the http request to execute, just use developper's tools in chrome to find a POST request with a URL like /s/echange/api/reporting/v1/generate/immediate/csv_searchsource.

When you find your request, try to execute it in your script : you will retrieve your csv's datas.

Comment: when I hit **download csv** button `POST` request is with this **url** `/api/reporting/v1/generate/immediate/csv/saved-object/search:3ba638e0-b894-11e8-a6d9-e546fe2bba5f` it's seem like `url` is been generating dynamic couln't able to find where it's been hit from

Comment: Not sure about "3ba638e0-b894-11e8-a6d9-e546fe2bba5f" token is. It could be a technical id from Kibana and in this case you maybe not have to change it. What do you have in your post's body ?